# My regression neural network stuck at certain accuracy

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, regression

I'm trying to build regression neural network. My problem is that accuracy metric during training from beginning remains at value 0.0027. I tried changing number of hidden layers and neurons, learning rate, optimizer, loss function, activation function of hidden layers and batch size. Unfortunately nothing seems to work. I even tried this without scaling output data (and without output activation function) and accuracy wasn't even bigger than zero (it was 0.0000e-4 or something like this) and loss was in fact decreasing but stuck at loss=56. So I suspect it has something to do with values scaling, but I don't know how to tackle this.

For purpose of building regression neural network I created my own fictional dataset. It's correlation between group (blue and pink), age, iq and results of some non-existant exam.

[image: scatter plot, result(age)]

[image: scatter plot, result(iq)]

After creating dataset I created neural network using TensorFlow. This is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from tensorflow import keras


def preprocess_dataframe(dataframe):
    for index, row in dataframe.iterrows():
        if row['group'] == 'blue':
            dataframe.at[index, 'group'] = 0
        else:
            dataframe.at[index, 'group'] = 1
    data = dataframe.to_numpy()
    data_X = np.delete(data, 3, 1)
    data_y = data[:, 3]
    data_y = np.asarray(data_y).astype(np.float32)
    data_y = data_y / 100
    X_train, X_val, X_test = data_X[:7000], data_X[7000:8500], data_X[8500:]
    y_train, y_val, y_test = data_y[:7000], data_y[7000:8500], data_y[8500:]
    scaler = StandardScaler()
    X_train_scaled = scaler.fit_transform(X_train)
    X_val_scaled = scaler.transform(X_val)
    X_test_scaled = scaler.transform(X_test)

    return X_train_scaled, X_val_scaled, X_test_scaled, y_train, y_val, y_test


df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')

X_train, X_val, X_test, y_train, y_val, y_test = preprocess_dataframe(df)

model = keras.models.Sequential([
    keras.layers.InputLayer(input_shape=[3]),
    keras.layers.Dense(30, activation='relu'),
    keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')
])

model.compile(
    loss='mse',
    optimizer=keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=0.01),
    metrics=['accuracy']
)

history = model.fit(
    X_train,
    y_train,
    epochs=1000,
    validation_data=(X_val, y_val)
)

model.evaluate(X_test, y_test)
```

And loaded dataframe looks like this:

```
       group  age          iq  result
0       blue   77  114.600366      47
1       blue   88  105.094111      52
2       pink   18  143.150909      39
3       blue   76   94.557100      34
4       pink   21  149.144244      40
...      ...  ...         ...     ...
9995    blue   68  179.515230      77
9996    blue   28  194.699500      74
9997    pink   20  166.325281      50
9998    blue   49   89.103387      28
9999    pink   36  185.689921      73
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is regression problem since the target is not a class, but a score (result divided by 100), while accuracy is metrics that works on classification. There are 3 solution I can propose to you :

1. Change the problem to classification problems. Make the target into a binary, maybe by using threhsold
2. Change the metrics you are using. Accuracy clearly is not the best metric to use since the value you are trying to predict is not categorical class. For alternative you can use mean_squared_error by supplying `loss='mean_squared_error'` to the `model.compile` instead of accuracy. You can learn more about classification metrics in [this link](https://towardsdatascience.com/the-5-classification-evaluation-metrics-you-must-know-aa97784ff226)
3. Change your network to follow regression task problem. The regression task is focus on predicting numerical value you can achieve this by setting your last dense layer as something else, maybe  `Relu` or just don't use activation at all at the final layer.
   **Update on this statement : If your value is tightly between 0 and 1, it's still okay to use sigmoid as the final activation layer since the value is squeezed between 0 and 1.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense :D So what metric should I look at to tell how good my network is doing? Loss value?

Comment: usually I just use mean_squared_error, or mean_absolute_error. Lower value indicate more accurate model